# Scroll View not Scrolling

Tags: android, layout, scroll, scrollview

I'm adding an image view to a linear layout, that linear layout is then added to scroll view. I'm displaying the scroll view with window manager, because this is all happening from a service. I can see the scroll bar, and when I drag up and down the scroll bar moves but the image views don't.

Here's my code:

```
// define the two views
    scroll = new ScrollView(this);
    trayAppList = new LinearLayout(this);

//define basic layout properties
trayAppList.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        width = 50;
        height = display.getHeight();

        // shortcut list container
        lstParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        lstParams.gravity = dockLocation;
        scroll.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, height));

//define window manager
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

//now display views

    scroll.setScrollContainer(true);
scroll.addView(trayAppList);
wm.addView(scroll, lstParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it as below:

```
ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(context);
scroll.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
scroll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
scroll.addView(yourTableView);
```

Comment: Tried that, FILL_PARENT made no difference, just move the scroll view to the top of the screen

Answer (score 0):

You have a fix height for trayAppList Linear layout as well as for "scroll" ScrollView. So the ScrollView is not able to scroll.

Make your ScrollView FILL_PARENT and see to it that the content in the scroll layout exceeds the screen then you will be able to scroll.

Comment: tried with FILL_PARENT, still the scroll bar moves but the images stay in the same place

Comment: Have you declared the image view inside the Linear Layout..?

Comment: Yes my images all show, they are all added to the linear layout but won't scroll, yet the scroll bar moves

Comment: Please see to it that you don't set image as background.

Answer (score 0):

Put your scroll layout inside of Linear Layout.

info_content_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.info_content_layout, null);
WindowManager.LayoutParams containerParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.addView(container, containerParams); 

LinearLayout listContainer = (LinearLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.list);
for(int x = 0 ; x <30 ; x++){
    View child =  LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    listContainer.addView(child);
}
```